# How to load all the tabs of a tabbar simultaneously in Android

Tags: android, tabbar

I have four tabs in tabbar. Whenever I launch my application I need to run all the tabs (four) of a tabbar, because all the tabs contains webviews that should be loaded whenever the app is launched. But the first tab should gets highlighted. I have used

```
setCurrentTab(0);
```

to load the first tab,but iam unable to load remaining tabs without clicking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, first create a xml file. The sample file is shown as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
    <TabWidget android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:paddingTop="70dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/viewTab1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <!-- Your view you want -->

    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/viewTab2">
        <!-- Your view you want -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Add as many view you want with unique id -->
</FrameLayout>
```

Each layout will refer to a unique layout.

In main activity use following

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 
TabSpec spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("FirstTabView");
TabSpec spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("SecondTabView");

spec1.setContent(R.id.viewTab1);
spec1.setIndicator("First Tab");

spec2.setIndicator("Second Tab");
spec2.setContent(R.id.viewTab2);

tabHost.addTab(spec1);
tabHost.addTab(spec2);

tabHost.setup();
```

You can add as many tabs needed. And this all will be initialized at same time.

I hope this helps you :)